# Animation does not work on android 4.x

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to implement a gallery which zoom in the center image like build-in gallery. on `onItemSelected` listener, I load a scale animation to make the center image bigger. Here is my code:

```
joinedProgramImages = new int[] { R.drawable.temp_lotteria_logo, R.drawable.temp_starbucks_logo, R.drawable.temp_cocacola_logo,R.drawable.temp_lotteria_logo, R.drawable.temp_starbucks_logo };
        JoinedProgramsAdapter adapter = new JoinedProgramsAdapter();
        galleryJoinedPrograms.setAdapter(adapter);
        galleryJoinedPrograms.setSpacing(-20);
        galleryJoinedPrograms.setSelection(1);
        galleryJoinedPrograms.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        galleryJoinedPrograms.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> viewgroup, View view, int position, long arg3) {
            //zoom out previous center image.
            if (selectedProgram != null) {
                Animation animation = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.statelist_zoomout_gallery_image);
                selectedProgram.startAnimation(animation);
                animation.startNow();
            }
            //zoom in the center image.
            Animation animation = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.statelist_zoomin_gallery_image);
            view.startAnimation(animation);
            selectedProgram = view;
            animation.startNow();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

The gallery's adapter:

```
private class JoinedProgramsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return joinedProgramImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return joinedProgramImages[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_joinedprogram_item, null);
            }
            ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_joinedPrograms_imageview_thumbnail);
            img.setImageResource(joinedProgramImages[position]);
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

The gallery image item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_joinedPrograms_imageview_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/temp_lotteria_logo" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The zoom-in animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:fillAfter="true"
>
<scale 
       android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:toXScale="3.50"
       android:fromYScale="1.0"
       android:toYScale="1.50"
       android:duration="200"
       android:pivotX="50%p"
       android:pivotY="50%p"
       android:fillAfter="true"/>

</set>
```

, and the zoom-out animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:fillAfter="true"
>
<scale 
       android:fromXScale="1.5"
       android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="1.5"
       android:toYScale="1.0"
       android:duration="200"
       android:pivotX="50%p"
       android:pivotY="50%p"
       android:fillAfter="true"/>

</set>
```

Everything is ok on android 2.x but It does not work on android 4.x. All image item have same size. Is there  any mistake here?
Please help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something similar to this :

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> viewgroup, View view, int position, long arg3) {
        //zoom out previous center image.
        if (selectedProgram != null) {
            Animation animation = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.statelist_zoomout_gallery_image);
            selectedProgram.startAnimation(animation);
            animation.startNow();
        }
        //zoom in the center image.
        Animation animation = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.statelist_zoomin_gallery_image);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_joinedPrograms_imageview_thumbnail);
        image.startAnimation(animation);
        //animation.startNow();
    }
```

I had almost the same issue while trying to set an animation of `GridView` items where the items were `ImageView`s and this trick worked for me on both Android 2+ and 4+. Just get an instance of the view which you want to use and play the animation as I guess in your situation should be something like

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_joinedPrograms_imageview_thumbnail);
```

and use this `image` for the animation.

Hope this works for you! : )

Comment: I tried your solution but It doesn't work perfectly. The image is zoom in but its' size does not change. It is zoom inside the bound.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldnt do it that way, the more easier way is to override ViewGroup.getChildStaticTransformation method, that way you have full control on the item, or even better ViewGroup.drawChild but the latter is much more difficult to use